# Android - How to get phone # from contacts

Tags: java, android

I want to get a phone number to dial from contacts , here is the code I'm testing:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);    

if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
               cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
        new String[]{id}, null);
        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
        // Do something with phones
        } 
        pCur.close();
    }
```

For some reason it gets error at 'new Sting[]{id}, null);
Eclipse error #1 -id cannot be resolved to a variable
Eclipse error #2 -type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to String

It appears maybe, as im a noob, 'id' is already being used by ArrayList ? But when i change 'id' to 'id2' Elcipse still dosent like it...

Please advise?

Thanks,
FlinxSYS

Comment: From the code you have posted, we cannot understand what is the variable 'id'. where have you defined 'id' and what is its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code for you:

```
    public static void getContacts(ContentResolver cr) {
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        // read id
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            // read names 
            String displayName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            // Phone Numbers 
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String typeStr = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
            }
            pCur.close();
...
```

Reference : http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-code-for-reading-phone-contacts.html

Comment: gt_ebuddy - where do I put my search contact name I pick, such as 'Sam' to have it get Sam's # from my contact list? I want to understand please.

Comment: you need to compare the 'displayName' with fixed name like "Sam" in your case. Try  printing all contact details(system.out.println) and play with this code first.....